# AD authentication vs SSO

Tags: authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on, spnego

Was wondering between the following scenarios:

1. App is integrated with AD. Users enter their AD credentials for authentication.
2. App uses SSO. SPNEGO, Kerberos etc.

Is 1 inherently less secure because username/password a sent through the wire?

Regards

Comment: Depends on how your app client/server channel is configured (i.e. SSL? SSH tunneling? no encryption at all?!?!)

Comment: ok...assuming no SSL or transit encryption at all. Is one less secure than the other?